# 1v1 game system rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a beginner with Rails so bear with me haha. I am trying to create a 1v1 type match system in Rails. The process I am trying to create is listed below with the current code I have attempted.

1. Allow user to create game.
2. Allow a different user to join that game.
3. If two users are in one match don't allow others to join.

Match model:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
```

end

Match controller:

```
class MatchesController < ApplicationController

before_filter :find_match, only: [:show, :join]

def index
    @matches = Match.all
end

def new
    @match = Match.new
end

def create
    @match = current_user.matches.new(match_params)

    if @match.save
        redirect_to root_url, notice: 'created.'
    else
        render('new')
    end
end

def join
    if @match.update_attributes(:opponent_id => current_user.id)
        redirect_to root_url, notice: 'joined.'
    else
        render('new')
    end
end

private
    def find_match
        @match = Match.find(params[:id])
    end
    def match_params
        params.require(:match).permit(:user_id, :opponent_id)
    end
```

end

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :matches
```

end

Match migration:

```
    create_table :matches do |t|
    t.string :match_title
    t.integer :user_id
    t.integer :opponent_id
    t.boolean :joinable
  t.timestamps
```

Thank you.

Comment: You asked no question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some small error. In 'join' method you should change condition:

```
def join

    if @match.joinable
        @match.update_attributes(:opponent_id => current_user.id, :joinable => false)
        redirect_to root_url, notice: 'joined.'
    else
        render('new')
    end
end
```

And add one line to 'create' method:

```
def create
    @match = current_user.matches.new(match_params)

    @match.joinable = true

    if @match.save
        redirect_to root_url, notice: 'created.'
    else
        render('new')
    end
end
```

Now, user can't join to matchs which has already 2 players.

Comment: I thought I was miles off haha. Thank you, this worked perfectly!

Comment: I have another question. How would I be able to access the user information from the 'opponent_id'?

Comment: @opponent = User.find(opponent_id)